# Symfony - can't get multiple file upload to work

Tags: symfony, file-upload, vichuploaderbundle

I'm using VichUploaderBundle to upload files for a gallery. I have two entities - the first one is Gallery, and the second is GalleryImage.

THis is the code: 
http://pastebin.com/2nWAK2iH - Gallery Entity 
http://pastebin.com/JWzWzZp2 - GalleryImage Entity 
http://pastebin.com/TnZr24Sp - GalleryImageType Form 
http://pastebin.com/9C8H25sn - GalleryType Form 
http://tny.cz/26e859f6 - The Controller (part of it)

No matter what I do, I always get
"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO GalleryImage (image_name, gallery_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, 8]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image_name' cannot be null"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
The new GalleryImage file: http://pastebin.com/uKtqg4HE

Comment: I tried to make it more readable, that's why I uploaded the code there. Anyway - the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `@Uploadable` class annotation is missing in the GalleryImage class.